# Can one rollerskate through Manchester and Newcastle airports?

Tags: uk, airports, manchester

I realy want to take my roller skates on my next holiday. I've heard of people roller skating through airports but that was in America.

I was wondering if this is allowed in uk airports? (Specifically Manchester and Newcastle airports) I've looked online and I can't find an answer on any website. I know I could just put them in my suitcase but they would take up a lot of room.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  Not an exact dupe, but relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107961/can-i-take-roller-skates-through-airport-security

Comment: In a lifetime of traveling (I'm 72), I have never seen rollerskating inside an airport terminal. It'd be great for sure - floors there are lovely clean surfaces - but I'd bet dollars to donuts that the first security person or policeman you see would not be pleased, and would stop you. Management is surely too frightened of collisions and falldowns and claims of damage to encourage or permit this.

Comment: Are you planning to wear skates into the aeroplane? I can see all sorts of safety issues with that. Even if you can skate through the terminal (unlikely) I'd bet money that the airline staff will stop you at the gate.

Comment: I frequently travel domestically and internationally. I have never seen anyone rollerskate/rollerblade in a terminal or airport in general. I have seen airport employees and security use bicycles and Segway-type vehicles. Mainly, these are used for outside the terminals. Although, I have seen them inside on rare occasions. Wearing them inside the aircraft will be a definite no-go. In an emergency, you become a hazard to others. You can not predict where and how you will have to egress. Over and above airport or airline policy, the captain has the last word on safety.